# Converting sequential Java to concurrent java code

Tags: java, project, concurrency

I am planning to do a project in Java in which I want to transform a  sequential Java code to a concurrent Java code and measure the efficiency .Any suggestions on which free source java application would be best for my project.Any other suggestions on how to go about it?

Thanks in advance
Deed

Comment: Do you already have the sequential Java code? You'll want to use Thread or Runnable to make it multi-threaded.

Comment: Hi Vanessa,
I do not have the sequential code.I need guidance on choosing the sequential code .Any free source Java application o your mind for my project?

Thanks,
Deed

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Java Concurrency Framework, which comes with JDK.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/

Comment: Hi Upul,
Thanks for the quick response.I kinda wanted to know which free source Java application would be the right choice for my project which is convert sequential code to concurrent code?
Thanks Deed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is whether the tasks that you are doing with your code can be run concurrently or not. If your code has been written as sequential, then you first need to identify what tasks can be run concurrently, what are the interdependencies between those tasks, whether they need to cooperate or whether they are independent. If they need to cooperate, you will need to have shared objects, locking etc. You need to decide whether you should use thread pools or create your own threads every time for every new task. Most of these would be very specific to your situation, so there can't be a generic answer. Once you have figured all that out check the java concurrency documentation on how to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am still searching for the sequential code .Needed help with that part.What do you think will be a reasonable Java application(free source) to start of with?

Comment: Your question is not very clear ... do you want an application to convert your sequential code to concurrent? I don't think there is any such application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution.

```
Runnable runnableObject = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      try {
      ... call your original logic ...
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      ... Exception handling ...
      } finally {
      ... final action ...
      }
  }
}

ArrayList listThreads = new ArrayList();
for (int i=0; i<CONCURRENT_THREADS_SIZE; i++) {
   Thread threadObject = new Thread(runnableObject, "mythread-" + i);
   threadObject.start();
   listThreads.add(threadObject);
}
```